# changing TRibbonGroups caption colors on a TRibbon control at Runtime

Tags: delphi, ribbon, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE-5 and the TRibbon control and I am trying to create Groups on each tab at runtime. If there is only one group on the tab, the font color of the group's caption is black.

[image: Single Group]

If there is multiple groups, the fonts are colored.

[image: Multi-group]

How do i make it so each groups caption is black? I tried changing the groups font color at runtime, but it did not work ( RGroup.Font.Color:= clBlack;)

Comment: I can't replicate the problem you're describing, and it's not apparent in the demo (Ribbon Demo) that ships with XE5. How do we produce this issue?

Comment: I do not know, I guess its on my machine then. I have had nothing but problems with the TRibbon control that comes with Delph XE5. I need to seek an alternative.

Comment: I have purchased the TMS control, it is much easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

It's an old subject, but in case someone is still intrested in that... You have to set also the group's color and then it will work!

```
 RGroup.Font.Color:= clBlack;
 RGroup.Color:= clBlack;
```